# Массив на Java

Tags: java

Как достать 2 элемента из массива в Java для проверки на Junit тесте?

```
package org.jazzteam;

public class PercentageRatio {

    public static int[] one() {

        int[] mas={0,0};
        String str = "Hello WROLD";
        int count = 0;
        int count1 = 0;
        int procent = 100;
        int otvet = 0;
        int otvet2 = 0;
        char chars[] = str.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(chars[i])) {
                count++;
            }
            if (Character.isLowerCase(chars[i])) {
                count1++;
            }

            otvet = procent * count / str.length();
            otvet2 = procent * count1 / str.length();

            if (otvet < otvet2) {
mas[0]=otvet2;

            } else {
                mas[1]=otvet;
                {
                }
            }
        }

        return mas;
    }

package org.jazzteam;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class PercentageRatioTest {

    @Test
    public void testone() {
        int[] result;
        result = PercentageRatio.one();
        assertEquals(54, result);

    }

    @Test
    public void testone1() {
        int[] result;
        result = PercentageRatio.one();
        assertFalse(result.equals(result));

    }

    @Test
    public void testone2() {
        int[] result;
        result = PercentageRatio.one();
        assertTrue(result.equals(result));

    }

}
```

т.е. из mas нужны в тест запихнуть 2 элемента, подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что-то у меня от кода Ваших тестов произошел разрыв шаблона. По индексам доставать и сравнивать лениво? У Вас всего 2 элемента. Еще как вариант можно сделать класс IntPair и возвращать его в качестве результата.

вообщем используйте assertArrayEquals и будет Вам счастье. И да, ваш result.equals(result) всегда true. Вы сравниваете объект с самим собой. Лучше будет так:

```
int[] expected = {50,50}; //подставьте свои числа
assertArrayEquals(expected, PercentageRatio.one());
```

Comment: Когда пытался сделать по индексам, выдавало ошибки (:

Comment: Дополнил ответ, смотрите javadoc по JUnit или используйте autocompletion в своей IDE :)

Comment: Спасибо большое :) Теперь все проходит

Comment: А там, где про истинное  выражение, это просто копия, забыл удалить :)

Comment: Да не за что, пометьте ответ как принятый пожалуйста

Comment: Прогнал еще так тест, тоже работает :) Ответ пометил)) Удачи

       @Test
 public void testone() {
  int[] result;
  result = PercentageRatio.one();
  assertEquals(36, result[0]);
  assertEquals(54,result[1]);